# how can I animate a circle over the curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, animate

I'm trying to put the circle over the curve but the operation generates an error, and I don't found how avoid this problem.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls]{10}
    \multiframe{25}{imdeg=0+1}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
        \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
        \path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (3pt);
        \path [fill=white] (0,0) circle (2pt); % círculo do ponteiro
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=100,domain=-5:5]   plot(\x,{(\x)^(2.0)});
        \draw[] (-5+\imdeg*0.4,(-5+\imdeg*0.4)^2) circle (2pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The problem is in (-5+\imdeg*0.4)^2, if the curve is y=x, then I'll use (-5+\imdeg*0.4) without the ^2 and works perfectly, but when I put ^2 .....ERROR!!!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you expect `^` to work as the power function? I think `\draw plot` uses gnuplot, and gnuplot uses `**` as power.

Comment: ok, it's clear your point, but ** does not work neither... my question is how do I do the power in this node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have error in writing of the following coordinate:

```
\draw[] (-5+\imdeg*0.4,(-5+\imdeg*0.4)^2) circle (2pt);
```

Correct is:

```
\draw[] (-5+\imdeg*0.4,{(-5+\imdeg*0.4)^2}) circle (2pt);
```

If you like to nest paranthesis `(...)` inside of some coordinates, you had to enclose them with curtly braces. Complete code

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls]{10}
    \multiframe{25}{imdeg=0+1}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
        \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
        \path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (3pt);
        \path [fill=white] (0,0) circle (2pt); % círculo do ponteiro
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=100,domain=-5:5]   plot(\x,{(\x)^(2.0)});
        \draw[] (-5+\imdeg*0.4,{(-5+\imdeg*0.4)^2}) circle (2pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

now works fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, that is an answer... thank you very much again....